# Some of the html entity code not visible in chrome browser ex: &#2053;

Tags: unicode, symbols, fromcharcode

Some of the entity code are unhandled in chrome browser, Please help and suggest alternate way to dispaly the symbols..

Entity code sample website link: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2000

Ex:

HTML Entity: (&)#x2053;  = ~

Thanks

Comment: Refer screenshot [link](https://15104268797498972201.googlegroups.com/attach/95bda2c280fea/htmlEntity.PNG?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrF4ZQUTmCHtolB5nDgOHdLjmxitKbC-n29rXiMLVJHNfsQqjalySgXwiNxv1d5pmysERkHFsO34yTqi67ROHlDiA8i1cLus1at0KyPHaEl9zdhhKZo)

Comment: Browser : Windows chrome Version 64.0.3282.167 32bit